# Moving a window between two positions

Tags: autohotkey

Hi I'm trying to make a macro that moves the active window between two positions,
but only if its actual position is one of the both defined.

```
X1 := (0.0395839*A_ScreenWidth)
Y1 := (0.049074*A_ScreenHeight)

X2 := (0.341146*A_ScreenWidth)
Y2 := (0.085185*A_ScreenHeight)


F1:: WinMove, A,, X1, Y1    ; works

F2:: WinMove, A,, X2, Y2    ; works

F3::                                ; doesn't  work. What am I doing wrong here?
WinGetPos, Xa, Ya,,, A
If (Xa ="X1" AND Ya = "Y1")
    WinMove, A,, X2, Y2
else
If (Xa = "X2" AND Ya = "Y2")
    WinMove, A,, X1, Y1
return
```

Comment: "`F1:: WinMove, A,, X1, Y1    ; works`" - really, this works? I can't imagine it to. Should rather be `F1:: WinMove, A,, %X1%, %Y1%`

Comment: @Blauhirn: WinMove is one of the few Commands that allow expressions and don't require variables to be surounded by %'s. https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you were trying to do is Compare variable Xa with a the String value of "X1" and not the Value contained in the Variable X1. You need to remove the quotes, like so:

```
F3::                                ; doesn't  work. What am I doing wrong here?
WinGetPos, Xa, Ya,,, A
If (Xa == X1 AND Ya == Y1)
    WinMove, A,, X2, Y2
else
If (Xa == X2 AND Ya == Y2)
    WinMove, A,, X1, Y1
return
```

Comment: EDIT 2 : "SetFormat, float, 03" and three digits after the decimal point did the trick. Thanks!